# How is Levenshtein distance related to ratio?

Tags: python

How is the ratio computed from the distance?

```
# https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/
>>> Levenshtein.distance('bjork gudmundsdottir', 'b. gudmundsson gunnar')
12
>>> len('bjork gudmundsdottir') + len('b. gudmundsson gunnar')
41
>>> Levenshtein.ratio('bjork gudmundsdottir', 'b. gudmundsson gunnar')
0.5853658536585366
```

I thought it was `(dist-len)/len`, but that seems incorrect. How is the above value of `0.58` arrived at?

Here is the closest I can get:

```
>>> Ldist / max(len( a ), len( b ))
>>> float(12)/21
0.5714285714285714
```

But still, this is off by `.01`. What would be the exact formula here?

Comment: Have you looked at how `Levenshtein.ratio` works?